# Establishing one to many relationship between 2 entities

Tags: core-data

I have an entity group and another entity as members.One particular group may have a number of members but a particular member belongs to one particular group only.In short i have a one to many relationship between group and member.How should i go about adding the relationship in my data model class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have added a relationship in group entity name Transaction  destination Transaction having inverse as Group and with TO-MANY option clicked

I have another relationship in Transaction entity named Group with optional clicked and having inverse to Transaction 

When i add a transaction (member) for a group it is getting added to all groups.

Comment: plz somebody answer to my query

Comment: Somebody plz help am struck here

Answer (score 1):

For your data model (ERM) You will want a foreign key in the member table pointing to the group table. eg:

Group table definition:

CREATE TABLE GROUP
(
  grp_id int,
  grp_name varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE MEMBER
(
  mbr_id int,
  mbr_grp_id int,
  mbr_name varchar(100)
)

... foreign key for mbr_grp_id ...